# Modifying app chooser in android

Tags: android, android-intent

I just wanna ask if it possible to create a chooser to which the user will select the activity he wants to perform. For example i have a capture button, when I click it, I want a chooser to appear containing CaptureImages, CaptureVideo, or RecordAudio. When the user select one of those it will redirect to their specific activity(intent).

Comment: i think you should try spinner. Have you tried using Spinner?

Comment: How is my answer working?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `AlertDialog.Builder` create a `Dialog` that shows a list with `setItems()`. Add a click listener to the list and check the return value, then do `startActivity(intent)` with the activity that the user selected.

Working example (startActivity is not implemented, you have to implement it to your needings):

```
String[] items = {"Selection 1", "Selection 2", "Selection 3"};

AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
builder.setTitle("Select something");
builder.setItems(items, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int item) {
        switch (item) {
            CASE 0:
                // startActivity(intent);
                break;
            CASE 1:
                // startActivity(intent);
                break;
            CASE 2:
                // startActivity(intent);
                break;
        }
    }
});
AlertDialog alert = builder.create();
alert.show();
```

Comment: I already used that and it works fine but I had to do it in other way to avoid complications with my other codes. But anyway thanks! I will still accept the answer.